# Cron функция не отрабатывает php скрипт

Tags: php, cron, openserver

Есть функция php которая лежит по адресу от корневого файла `cron\update.php` в ней находиться просто тестовый код, который генерирует txt страницы.

```
<?php file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/cron/'.date('H-i-s_d-m-Y').'.txt', "123");
```

Функция проверена и она отрабатывает. При создании cron запроса который по идеи должен выполняться каждую минуту OpenServer

`%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php-win.exe -c %progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php.ini -q -f %sitedir%\btsports.loc\cron\update.php`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта функция не срабатывает. Можете подсказать в чём может быть проблема?
*В логах запросы вижу, но результата выполнения - нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "В логах запросы вижу, но результата выполнения - нет"  --- тогда без всякого крона запускай файл и дебажь. Возможно проблема в скрипте

Comment: Сам скрипт рабочий, если его просто запускать от браузера.  `http:btsports.loc\cron\update.php` он создает файлы.

Comment: крон - это не веб. в локально запускаемом скрипте нет `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, эту переменную нужно задать вручную, возможно из-за этого не отрабатывает. Пропишите базовый каталог как `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))`

Comment: заменил в файле на `<?php file_put_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).date('H-i-s_d-m-Y').'.txt', "123");` теперь и просто функция не стартует.

Comment: а ошибки то выдает какие то?

Comment: Случилось чудо) Оставил работать крон на ночь, оказывается, что `file_put_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).date('H-i-s_d-m-Y').'.txt', "123");`  Создает, файл, но только не в той дерриктории. А в корневом файле. и файлы имеют значение - `cron11-51-01_16-11-2022.txt` Можете, подсказать, ответом, как должен выглядеть запрос что б создавало именно в `/cron/`

Comment: PS Если прописать `file_put_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/cron/'.date('H-i-s_d-m-Y').'.txt', "123");` крон ничего не создает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так выглядел путь, если крон файл из другой дериктории запускаеться:

`<?php  file_put_contents('E:\\OSPanel\\domains\\test.loc\\cron\\' . date('H-i-s_d-m-Y') . '.txt', "123");`

или короткая запись

`<?php file_put_contents(__DIR__. '\\' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . '.txt', '123');`

Answer (score 1):

Cron - не браузер. При запросе HTTP-сервер (Apache, Nginc, etc.) добавляют свои стандартные и общепринятые поля.
Cron - это консольный запуск.

Чтоб дебажить такие приложения, добавьте в `PATH` папку интерпретатора PHP. Далее запускайте файл из консоли и смотрите результат выполнения.
Только учтите что переменные `%phpdriver%` и `%progdir%` - переменные чисто OpenServer'а, и их лучше прописать явно.

---

К решению вашей проблеммы. Во первых, как уже сказали, в консоли нету `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`. Поэтому лучше отталкиватся от директории, в которой лежит скрипт.
Так же, в коде, что вы указали в комментариях, вы пытаетесь создать файл в папке, которая не существует. В таком случае папка сама не создадится.

Поэтому нужно её создать. Вот такое решение получилось у меня:

```php
<?php
$logDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cron";
$logFilename = $logDirectory . "/" . date("H-i-s_d-m-Y") . ".txt";
if(!is_dir($logDirectory)){
  mkdir($logDirectory);
}

file_put_contents($logFilename, "123");
```

---

Совет который меня не просили:
Лучшая практика формата временной метки для имен файлов - "Y-m-d_H-i-s". В таком случае, при сортировке файлов по имени они будут идти в хронологическом порядке.
У вас же (например), вы сначала увидите в папке все файлы за месяц, что были сделаны в 1 час, потом в 2 часа, пото в 3 часа.

Comment: Директория **cron** существует. Так как файл скрипта лежит в этой директории.  И в этом случае ``$logDirectory = __DIR__;``

И да в PHP есть константа ``___DIR__`` которая делает то же самое что и ``dirname(__FILE__)``

Comment: @Давид Манжула , спасибо, но Ваш пример, не отрабатывает. Оно нигде ничего не создает. Ставлю на вывод каждую минуту `*/1 * * * *` но не срабатывает.

Comment: @newman не то же самое =)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 только что запустил - у меня работает. Но я ставил время просто "* * * * *" без /1

Comment: @ДавидМанжула а вот документация к PHP говорит что тоже самое https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.magic.php

Comment: @newman беру свои слова назад. Точно помню, что они отличались, если запускать из консоли из другой папки или инклудить файлы. Но счас провел експеримент и оказался не прав. Прошу прощения

Comment: Если даже в исполняющем файле в лоб прописать `<?php file_put_contents('E:\OSPanel\domains\test.loc\cron' . date('H-i-s_d-m-Y') . '.txt', "123");`, то cron отрабатывает и создает, НО не в дериктории test.loc\cron, а просто в корневой папке test.loc Как это исправить ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
<?php file_put_contents(__DIR__ . date('H-i-s_d-m-Y') . '.txt', "123");
```

Comment: Создает, но в корневой папке локального сайта.

Comment: А надо именно что б в `mysite.loc/cron`

Comment: Ну значит у вас скрипт лежит не в папке **cron**, а в корневой папке. Значит добавьте в строчку путь до папки:   "/cron/"  и все будет

Comment: `<?php file_put_contents(__DIR__. '/cron/' . date('H-i-s_d-m-Y') . '.txt', "123"); `  Такая запись не работает.